# How to run multiple union query in MySQL on multiple connection?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a few connections in MySQL ie different hostname as well as schemas and I want export the data by joining the query into

1. Connection Name: Australia
   Hostname: xx07xx130300_001.db.6567xxx.xxx.com
   Schema:  xx07xx130300_001
2. Connection Name: Indonesia
   Hostname: xx07xx130300_002.db.6567xxx.xxx.com
   Schema: xx07xx130300_002
3. Connection Name: Singapore
   Hostname: xx07xx130300_003.db.6567xxx.xxx.com
   Schema: xx07xx130300_003

How do I do union in this case in MySQL Workbench?

The field that I use is Email and LastModified and they are all on the same on each connection.

Can I do something like this:

```
SELECT Email, LastModified FROM Australia.xx07xx130300_001.table1
UNION 
SELECT Email, LastModified FROM Indonesia.xx07xx130300_002.table1
UNION
SELECT Email, LastModified FROM Singapore.xx07xx130300_003.table1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

A query cannot span multiple connections. You can fake it by using [Federated tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html), which transparently link tables in other db instances to the local DB instance. That'll issue a single query to the local DB server, and it'll handle the background work of farming the query off to the foreign DB instances.

Comment: MarcB: How do I do this on MyWorkbench then?

Comment: Read the docs I linked to. Once you've linked the 'foreign' DB servers to your current DB server as federated tables, then your union query should work, since it'd be exactly like doing a union query on multiple local tables. The federated engine will transparently send the relevant query to the remote server.